# ヘルプページを翻訳しましょう！

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

数か月前から、ヘルプページに英語のページがいくつか現れるようになりました。ヘルプページは Transifex や Traducir には登録されないため、メタ経由で直接翻訳する必要があります。少しずつ翻訳を進めていくために、この投稿では翻訳が完了していないヘルプページをリスト化します。

### 翻訳が完了していないヘルプページ一覧

- 質問にあたって

  - <del>[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) -> ([ドラフト)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2980/14055)</del> -> 完了
  - <del>[I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) -> [(ドラフト)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3006/3060)</del> -> 完了
  - <del>[How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) -> [(ドラフト)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3238/32986)</del> -> 完了
- 弊社のモデル

  - <del>[What is Flair?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flair) -> [(ドラフト)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2943/19110)</del> -> 完了
  - <del>[What browsers do we support?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) ->[（ドラフト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3120/14055)）</del> -> 完了
- 信用度とモデレーション

  - <del>[What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) -> [(ドラフト)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3068/19110)</del> -> 完了

### メモ

- ヘルプに書かれることは今後の方針の参考にされるため、少し慎重に訳すと安心です。
- 訳している途中で何か問題があれば、その点をメタに投稿してヘルプページの内容自体を変えてしまうこともできます。
- 翻訳の流れ：

  1. それぞれのヘルプページの翻訳のためのメタ投稿を作る。最初は英語をそのまま載せるので OK です。
  2. メタ投稿を直接編集する形で翻訳を進める。最初は意味を大きく変えないように訳し、その後何か意見があれば、コメントや別のメタ質問を使って議論を進める。
  3. 議論が収束して翻訳が安定したら、モデレーターが翻訳をヘルプに反映させる。

Comment: 翻訳が済んだものはリストから削除してしまうより、打消し線で残しておく方がモチベーションに繋がるかなと個人的に思いました。みんなの協力で作業は進んでいるので、消してしまうと "無かったこと" みたいな扱いに感じます。

Comment: これ翻訳の流れの1番でMETA投稿をベースに翻訳する。とありますが、未翻訳のものはまだ投稿ない感じですか？、あとMETA投稿があるなら、翻訳済みのものも含めてそちらのリンク先が欲しい感じがします。翻訳はゆっくりでとりあえずバシバシ誰かが作るだけ作ってもいいのかなぁと思ったり……

Comment: @Sieg さん、はい、ここにリンクが無いものはまだメタに投稿がありません。気付いた方が適宜メタ投稿を作って翻訳していく形をとっています。こうしている理由は特になくて、単に誰もしていないから無いというだけですね :-)

Comment: @nekketsuuu すれ違いました()。そういうことですね。

Comment: @Sieg ヘルプは不定期に内容(ページ)が追加されることがあるので、モデレーターでも定期的にチェックをしていないと更新に気づかない場合があります。そういった意味で「気づいた人がメタに投稿」という手法になっています。

Comment: ※ タイトルの文字数制限により編集が行なえないため、こちらにコメントしておきます。[How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) と [What is Flair? のドラフト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943/)のリンク先 URL が別のページを指しているようです。

Comment: @supa さん、ありがとうございます。私が編集しようとしても文字数制限で弾かれたので、タイトルの文字数を増やしておきました（どこかの挙動が変わったのかもしれません……）