# ヘルプセンター翻訳："What is Flair?" について

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプ センター > 弊社のモデル
[What is Flair?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flair) の翻訳です。改善案がありましたら直接編集、またはコメントで指摘をお願いします。

---

### プロフィールバナーとは何ですか？

プロフィールバナーはあなたの実績（信用度やバッジ、参加サイト）をまとめた画像です。あなたのウェブサイト等に掲載するのに適しています。もちろん印刷してベストにつけて着用したり、ということもできるのかもしれませんが実際にする人はごく少数でしょう。

#### 例：

[image: プロフィールバナーの例です。アイコン、名前、信用度、バッジの数が記載されています。]
詳細については、ログインして自分のプロフィールの[設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current)をご覧ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSEによると](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371702/314875)リンクが少し前に削除されていました。合わせて、[日本語版ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/flair)での YouTube リンクも（少し遅くなってしまいましたが‍♀️）削除しました。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

反映が完了いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]