# ヘルプセンター翻訳: "Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?"

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプ センター > 質問にあたって
[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) の翻訳ドラフトです。直接編集どうぞよろしくお願いします。

---

### 別の質問をしようとするとシステムから1日以上待つように言われました。これはなぜですか？

質問することが時に難しく思えることもあるでしょう。スタック・オーバーフローでは各ユーザーが可能な限り素晴らしい経験を経て欲しいと思っています。あなたが最近投稿した質問のいくつかはコミュニティからあまり良い評判を得られなかったようです。次の投稿をする前に少し休憩を取りサイトを詳しく読んでみてはいかがでしょうか。

ここで最もお勧めしたい手法は、あなたが興味を持つ[タグ](/tags)を選択し、最も高く評価された質問から投票数によってソートすることです：

[image: sorting]

高く評価された質問には共通点がいくつか見られます：

- 文法や句読点ができるだけ正しく使用され、読みやすい
- 「何を解決したいのか」が明確に述べられており、他のユーザーが再現できるよう、問題に関するコードの詳細等が含まれている
- *明確* で *記述的* なタイトルがついている
- 前置きがなく、読み易く理解し易い

高く評価された質問を読むことに時間をかけた後には、以前あなたが投稿した質問に戻ってそれらを改善、編集してみてはいかがでしょうか。また、あなたが答えられる質問を探し、それらに素晴らしい回答を投稿することもできます。これまでたくさんの質問や回答がすでになされているので、少し時間をかけて、[検索の仕組みを理解する](/help/searching)こともお勧めします。

もし、まだ読んでいないのであれば、コミュニティからのアドバイスとして[良い質問をするには?](/help/how-to-ask)、[どのような質問は避けるべきですか?](/help/dont-ask)、をご一読ください。

***質問の制限はあくまで一時的なものですが、システムではより長い制限を行う場合があります。*** システムがあなたのアカウントからの質問をさらに長期間にわたって制限してしまうことを避けるために、出来るだけ多くのアドバイスをお伝えしようとしています。可能であれば、もう一度あなたが投稿した質問に戻ってそれらを改善してください。

時間が経てば新しい質問をすることができるようになるでしょう。しかし、質問を投稿する前にあなた自身で調査をすることを忘れないでください。そして、本当に行き詰まった時に*だけ*質問するようにしてください。あなたが質問しなければならない時には上記のガイダンスにどうぞ従うようにしましょう。そうすれば、誰もが気持ち良く参加できるようになるでしょう。

Comment: 翻訳されている部分に直接手を入れていいかわからなかったですが、触ってみました。（もし変なら直してください）

Comment: @Sieg どんどん編集してくださいね！よろしくお願いします m_ _m。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

反映が完了いたしました。

[image: ヘルプセンター日本語訳]