# ヘルプセンター翻訳: What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は [What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) の翻訳案です。

---

### 通報が却下された時はどうしたらいいですか？

#### 却下された通報とはなんですか？

「却下済み」はモデレーター（もしくは他の信頼された人）が、あなたの行った[通報](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)への対応を拒否したことを意味します。

#### なぜ私の通報が却下されたのでしょうか？

通報が却下される場合、いくつかの理由が考えられます。

- あなたが見つけた問題は、他の人が全く問題と感じないものだった
  (例: あなたは質問をオフトピックとしてクローズすることを提案したが、その質問の内容は[このサイトのトピック](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)に沿ったものだった)。
- あなた自身で対応できる簡単な問題だった場合
  (例: 間違った回答を通報した場合。マイナス投票で示したり、編集して正しい回答にすることができるでしょう)。
- 通報が確認された時点で既に問題が解決していた場合
  (例: あなたが通報した後に投稿者が編集した)。
- 問題が一見わかりにくいもので、通報を確認した人が見逃してしまった場合
  (例: 釣りリンクの書かれたコメントを暴言/スパムとして通報したが、対応したモデレーターがリンク先の確認を忘れてしまった)。

モデレーターは通報を却下した理由を書き残していることが多いです。これらは、[あなたの通報履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current)から確認することができます。

#### 通報が却下された時はどうすべきですか？

特にしなければならないことはありませんが、問題が継続しているのをどうにかしたい場合は、次の点を意識してください。

1. 上の説明を参考に、通報が却下された理由を考えてみましょう。対応した人がなにか見落としていたかもしれません。場合によっては、あなた自身がなにか見落としていたことに気づくかもしれませんが、そこから学ぶいい機会となるでしょう。
2. 次に、あなたが通報した投稿やコメントを確認して、問題が継続しているかを確認します。もし問題が解決していたり、あまり重要な問題ではなさそうだったら、ここで終わります。

問題がまだ継続していたら、以下のように自分で解決できないか考えてみてください。

- 投稿に[マイナス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)をすることで、他のユーザーに警告することができませんか？
- [投稿を編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)して、投稿者の意図を残したまま問題を修正することはできませんか？

もし自分で解決できる問題であれば、通報する必要はありません。解決しましょう！

もし、それがあなただけで対応できるような問題ではなく、モデレーターの見落としだろうと思うのであれば、問題の詳細を添えて「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として通報することもできます。これを使って、問題をより詳しく説明したり、最初の通報で見落されてしまった点について示すとよいでしょう。

あなたとモデレーターの意見の違いから通報が却下された場合、[メタに問題提起する](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)こともできます。これは、コミュニティ全体の前であなたの意見を主張するチャンスであり、なにを許すか、なにが適切か、といったコミュニティのルールを変えることに同意を得られるかもしれません。時間をかけて提案を書き、その変更によってどのようにサイトをよくすることができるか、具体例を盛り込むとよいでしょう。

#### わたしの通報がたくさん却下されるとどうなりますか？

通報のいくつかが却下されると、通報履歴ページで確認することを勧める警告が表示されます。これはそれらの通報に確認する機会を与えるものです。

過去7日間において、10件以上の通報のうち25%が却下されると、一時的に通報ができなくなります。この措置は最大7日間続き、その後再び通報が可能になります。通報ができない期間は過去に行なった通報を再度確認し、このヘルプページを読み返すなど大切な情報を得るために設けられています。このコミュニティは皆の協力が必要であることをどうぞ忘れないでください。そして問題を解決するためにうまく協力することができれば、スタック・オーバーフローはさらに素晴らしい場所になるでしょう。

#### 参考:

- [投稿の通報 権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)
- [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)
- [Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

反映が完了いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]