# ヘルプセンター翻訳："What browsers do we support?"

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は [What browsers do we support?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) の翻訳案です。

---

### どのブラウザに対応していますか？

スタック・オーバーフローは、主要なブラウザについて新しい方から2つの安定版に対応しています。ベータ版／開発版は含まれません。

対応しているブラウザは、[Browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)の設定文字列を使って表示すると[このようになります](https://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%2011%2C%20not%20dead%2C%20not%20op_mini%20all%2C%20not%20baidu%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_ff%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_qq%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20kaios%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20op_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20ie_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_uc%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Samsung%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Android%20%3E%200)。

お使いのブラウザがこのリストにない場合でも動作することはありますが、エクスペリエンスが低下します。

Comment: bikeshedですが原文の時点からbrowserlistではなくbrowserslistの方が正確なような。

Comment: @nekketsuuu テクニカルタームありがとうございますm_ _m！そうですね「browserslist」やんわりと[Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52311726#52311726)で聞いてみました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

反映が完了いたしました。（browserslistが正しいのかどうかはリプライがなかった為不明ですが、一旦上の形で反映されております m_ _m。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]